# processing TSV embedded with JSON using jq?

Tags: jq

```
$ jq --slurp '.[] | .a' <<< '{"a": 1}'$'\n''{"a": 2}'
1
2
```

I can process a one-column TSV file like above. When there are multiple columns and one column is JSON, how to print the processing result of the JSON column alone with other columns literally? In the following example, how to print the first column and the JSON processing result of the 2nd column?

```
$ jq --slurp '.[] | .a' <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Before piping your TSV file into `jq` you should extract the JSON column first. For instance, use `cut` from GNU coreutils to get the second field in a tab-separated line:

```sh
cut -f2 <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}' | jq --slurp '.[] | .a'
```

In order to print the other columns as well, you may use `paste` to put the columns back together:

```sh
paste <(
  cut -f1 <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}'
) <(
  cut -f2 <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}' | jq --slurp '.[] | .a'
)
```

To solve this entirely in `jq` you have to read it as non-JSON first and interpret the second column as JSON using jq's `fromjson`

```
jq -Rr './"\t" | .[1] |= (fromjson | .a) | @tsv' <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}'
```

Comment: I'd rather not to duplicate the input. Is there a way to just use jq to process a TSV file with JSON as a column? Alternatively, maybe there is a wrapper of jq in python so that I can use python to extract the column of a TSV and still use the jq syntax to process the extract JSON content?

Comment: Added a jq-only solution to my answer.

Comment: I don't see the definition of `./"\t"` in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/. Do you know where it is documented?

Comment: Under section "Multiplication, division, modulo": `Dividing a string by another splits the first using the second as separators`. It's equivalent to `split("\t")`.

Comment: How to extract two fields or more? I tried ```$ jq -Rr './"\t" | .[1] |= (fromjson | [.a, .b]|@tsv) | @tsv' <<< $'A\t{"a": 1, "b": 2}'```. But `\t` is not converted to a TAB.

Comment: Your first `@tsv` does indeed produce a tab, but the second `@tsv` receives the whole result as one data column and accordingly escapes special characters such as the tab.

Comment: So how to fix the problem so that the result of the first @tsv  is not escaped?

Comment: My original approach did not alter the number of columns (just converted the json-column into one value). Your new constraint requires building all columns from scratch: `jq -Rr './"\t" | [.[0], (.[1] | fromjson | .a, .b)] | @tsv' <<< ...`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
jq --raw-input --raw-output --slurp 'split("\n") | map(split("\t")) | map(select(length>0)) | .[] | {"p":.[0], "j":.[1] | fromjson} | [.p, .j.a] | @tsv' <<< $'A\t{"a": 1}'$'\nB\t{"a": 2}'

A   1
B   2
```

or process line by line for huge data

```sh
cat ./data.txt | while read line;
do
    echo "$line" | jq --raw-input --raw-output --slurp 'split("\t") | {"p":.[0], "j":.[1] | fromjson} | [.p, .j.a] | @tsv'
done
```